# Horizontally Autoscaled Kubernetes pods not pulling messages from Google Cloud Pub/Sub subscription

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-pubsub, horizontal-scaling

Our application is running on `Google Kubernetes Engine` and pulling messages from a `Google Cloud Pub/Sub` Subscription. We have one pod running in idle state, and horizontal pod autoscaling is set up to 10 pods depending on cpu usage. The subscription is mostly empty, and when a batch job kicks in, it writes into to Pub/Sub topic. The autoscaling is working well. It immediately (within 30 seconds) scales up to 10 pods once there are outstanding messages in the Pub/Sub subscription. But the issue is only a few pods are pulling the messages from the subscription and rest of them are just sitting even though there are still messages in the subscription.

Pub/Sub Client settings are:

```
MaxExtension: 600
MaxOutstandingMessages: 100 (also tried with 25)
Synchronous: true (also tried with false)
```

Google Cloud Pub/Sub Subscription Settings:

```
Pull-based
Ack Deadline is 600 seconds
```

And once the batch job kicks in, it writes 20k messages into the Pub/Sub topic. And the application can process 2 messages/sec in average.

The application is written in `golang` and we're using `cloud.google.com/go v0.44.1` package version.

Do you know why the pods are sitting and not pulling messages even though there's a backlog in the Cloud Pub/Sub subscription?

Comment: How many pods are sitting? in average?

Comment: Most of the time 8 out of 10 are sitting. In the worst case, only one pod is running, rest are waiting. When I kill the one which is consuming messages, the others start to consume messages.

Comment: Is it possible that all your clients have the same subscription ID? Please add an [mcve] to your question by [editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58234853/edit).

Comment: @mdtp did you find the answer? @Markus I have created one subscription on GCP. My service is subscribing to that subscription and calling `recieve`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to set this:

```
    sub.ReceiveSettings.NumGoroutines = 10 * runtime.NumCPU()
    sub.ReceiveSettings.MaxOutstandingMessages = -1
    sub.ReceiveSettings.MaxOutstandingBytes = -1
```

Maybe by removing some limit, it could be better?

let me know

Comment: ``` // If the value is negative, then there will be no limit on the number of
 // unprocessed messages.```

Comment: I am facing same exact problem. It is one subcription that my service is using and pulling sync. So GCP should distribute messages but I see all of them going to mostly one pod.